# Where do I enter CMD line prompts for MavensMate for Windows?

Tags: ide, mavensmate, sublime, windows7

I have recently started using MavensMate as a replacement for Eclipse with the Force.com IDE.

The MavensMate [docs](http://mavensmate.com/API/Overview) have a bunch of helpful CMD line prompts, I'm pretty new to Sublime and I don't know all it's ins and outs...

Where do I enter these prompts?

Is there a special Sublime / MavensMate CMD line I can access through Sublime?

Do I just enter them in my regular CMD line and if so, do I navigate the folder into which I downloaded Sublime or MavensMate?

I'm hesitant to start firing commands off in my CMD line in the wrong folders in case I cause some irreversible damage.

**UPDATE**

To be clear, I'm looking to enter [Command Line Prompts](http://mavensmate.com/API/Overview) and not [MavensMate Shortcuts](http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Shortcuts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commands should be run from within your project's directory. Non-project specific commands can be run from anywhere.

Example of a non-project specific command (opens up new project UI):

```
mm new-project --ui
```

Example of a project-specific command (compiles project):

```
cd path/to/your/project
mm compile_project
```

Example of piping data to a command (compiles a series of files):

```
cd path/to/your/project
mm compile <<< '{"files": ["path/to/some/apex/class.cls"]"}'
```

The most comprehensive resource, as of my writing this, for examples of commands/payloads is the `mm` test suite. You can run all tests for `mm` by cd'ing to the `mm` root and running:

```
python test --api=31.0
```

This will produce output like this for every command in the test suite:

```
[new_project] ------->

[STDIN] -->

{"username": "someusername@force.com", "project_name": "unit test project", "package": {"ApexClass": ["CompileAndTest"]}, "org_type": "developer", "action": "new", "password": "somepassword"}

[STDOUT] -->

{
    "body": "Project Retrieved and Created Successfully",
    "body_type": "text",
    "success": true,
    "time": "4.19424295425415"
}
```

Comment: I know this is marked as answered but I don't think it was. The answer is much different than the question. For instance there is an example of deploying using the API (Not the UI). Where do you actually enter the "{ "project_name" etc that is listed in the Help documentation? I have the same question as a new Mavensmate user and not getting answer from here.

Answer (score 2):

So, I use a Mac, and I'm sure this key-combo is slightly different but what you want to do is bring up the command palette. On a mac thats Shift-Cmd-P. Googling reveals it's control-shift-p on winders.

Once you open the command palette, you can start typing the name of the command you want to run ie: deploy, or apex class, or trigger etc. Select what you're looking for and hit enter. Doing so will cause Sublime to automatically run the command line for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin, but I'm actually looking to enter [Command Line Promts](http://mavensmate.com/API/Overview), not MavensMate [shortcuts](http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Shortcuts).

Comment: Well, in that case you'd enter them in your terminal window. or powershell window.